# Remove trailing with redirect now WWW to WWW

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to remove all Trailing Slash from my URL. Example:

```
This: mysite.com/category/ or mysite.com/category/id1/
```

I want this (**remove /**):

```
To: mysite.com/category or mysite.com/category/id1
```

And I have serious problems to adapt regex with my .htaccess
Sorry!

This is my current .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
#-- custon error pages
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
#-- enable RewriteEngine and use parameter "p" --
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
#-- now WWW to WWW --
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Merry Christmas! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to escape characters in the target url.

I  corrected/reorded your htaccess rules ,and added a Rule to remove trailing slash(s).

```
Options -Indexes
#-- custon error pages
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
#-- enable RewriteEngine and use parameter "p" --
RewriteEngine On
#-- now WWW to WWW --
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

#Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/+$ $1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/+$ $1 [L,R]` - Since this is an external redirect, you'll likely need a slash prefix on the substitution. ie. `/$1`, to avoid the directory-prefix being added. (Or set `RewriteBase`)

Comment: @w3d yes! best answer here! works flawless, thanks! :)